# How to perform FFT for I(real) & Q(imaginary) arrays?

Tags: signal, fft

I have two arrays namely **I** & **Q**, each array contains **1024** points. Now I'm trying to perform FFT using [Cooley Tukey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm).

[image]

According to the picture above, the number of input points are `8`, in my case, I have two sets of 1024 points(I & Q arrays), so what would be the size of input of a Butterfly diagram ?

Answer (score 1):

At each loop of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm, the butterfly diagram of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm always has the same number of inputs to the butterfly diagram as the number of inputs in that loop.

Looking at the graphic in your question, we see there are 8 inputs.  The butterfly diagram is the right half of your picture which has 8 inputs, 4 labeled E and 4 labeled O.  Now to find E and O we have to do two individual instances of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm loop and these will have N/2=4 inputs each, so the butterfly diagrams in these instances will be have 4 inputs.

Comment: sorry if I'm not clear, as mentioned above `I have 2 sets of arrays I & Q of 1024 points each`, now all I want to know is that the required number of input points(i.e x[0],x[1]....x[?])

Comment: How are you treating I an Q? It sounds like you have X = I + iQ and are trying to do FFT on each I and Q separately.  In this case you will need 1024.

Comment: Yeah, so far what I 've done was I've sampled a signal @ 10MHz, and captured 1024 samples (I = 1024 points, Q=1024 points), now am trying to perform FFT to these, as per your statement if I consider 1024 points what happens to the remaining 1024 points?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you want to compute the FFT of I using Cooley-Tukey and then Q. So there will be two instances each of 1024. Strictly speaking in terms of Cooley-Tukey, you don't need to break things up as real and imaginary but often times people are more comfortable with real functions.

Comment: I agree with you, the hardware that I have can only provide I & Q Samples, and then I need to process them through one of the FFT algorithm.!

Comment: Assuming the samples I_k and Q_k are the real and imaginary parts of a sample of a complex signal then you just want to feed in x_k = I_k+iQ_k into your FFT algorithm.

Comment: When I say I & Q data, this is what I meant : http://whiteboard.ping.se/SDR/IQ and thanks for the suggestion, I will try that.